# Controle de Radios Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho o seguinte código a baixo onde queria fazer o controle dos rádios.
Quero que haja um "evento" disparado quando o each terminar de varrer todo o grupo de radios 1 cujo o name é "grupo1".Ou seja, no final de cada grupos de rádios varridos seja emitido uma mensagem ou uma variável mude seu status.
ex: quando chegar no grupo1 com value 4 seja emitido uma mensagem.Quando chegar no ultimo elemento do grupo2 também deve ser disparo "evento".
Isso tem de ser DINÂMICO.Para qualquer outro ou quantidade de elementos radios.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#botao").click(function() {

    $("textarea[name='arraytextArea[]'],input[name='grupo1'],input[name='grupo2']").each(function(i, el) {
      alert("Valor:" + $(el).val());
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <textarea name='arraytextArea[]'></textarea> <br>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="Valor1"><span>Valor1</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="Valor2"><span>Valor2</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="Valor3"><span>Valor3</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="Valor4"><span>Valor4</span>

    <br><textarea name='arraytextArea[]'></textarea> <br>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="Valor1"><span>Valor2</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="Valor2"><span>Valor3</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="Valor3"><span>Valor4</span>

    <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="Valor4"><span>Valor5</span><br>

    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="botao">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não seria só colocar um alert após o final do foreach? não sei se te entendi corretamente.

Comment: realizei outra pergunta ...Essa pergunta foi mal formulada.Falei o que realmente quero fazer nesse link :https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279667/concatenar-elementos-radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer uma função para "agrupar" todos os inputs pelo name
e conta-los

Use o seguinte codigo

```
 $(function () {
    $("#botao").click(function () {
        var inputs =  $(":radio");
        var grupos = [];
    
        var fe = $.each(inputs,function(){
        var nome = $(this).attr("name");
            if(typeof grupos[nome] === 'undefined'){
                grupos[nome] = 0;
           }
           grupos[nome] = grupos[nome] + 1;
        })
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(grupos);
        },1000)
    })
});
```

A saida será igual a **[grupo1: 4, grupo2: 4]**
Você pode ver um [exemplo  funcionando  aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/4hg1238L/21/)

Você poderá obter os valores da seguinte forma
grupos['grupo1'];
grupos['grupo2'];
ou qualquer outro nome que esteja usando

Comment: Observer que estou logando o valor no console então aperte f12 para ver o  resultado

Comment: É realmente a pergunta foi mal formulada.Na verdade eu queria saber quando o each estivesse no ultimo elemento de cada grupo pois, minha intenção era concatenar cada elemento span de acordo com o grupo que ele faça parte